# Transclude nested child element

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-components, angularjs-ng-transclude, transclusion

I am writing a set of maps components and one of my components requires a popup to be shown when a map marker has the mouse over. This is dealt with by `mapMarkerPopup` inside `mapMarkers`.

Unfortunately this doesnt work. I think its because the transclusion slot I am trying to use is not in the direct parent. Is this why? Also if it is why what can I do about it?

**Note 1** that due to the way the maps work ANY visible [non maps] HTML must be placed outside the `ui-gmap-google-map` directive

**Note 2** that `mapClickHandler` does a similar job to the `mapMarkerPopup` but is a direct child of the map component and works.  But it is the `mapMarkerPopup` I am having an issue with.

Here is how the overall HTML looks

```
<my-map>
    <map-click-handler>...</map-click-handler>
    <map-markers></map-markers>
</my-map>
```

Here are how the components are setup, only relevant parts are shown.

**myMap.html**

```
<ui-gmap-google-map>
    <ng-transclude></ng-transclude>
</ui-gmap-google-map>

<ng-transclude ng-transclude-slot="mapClickHandler"></ng-transclude>
<ng-transclude ng-transclude-slot="mapMarkerPopup"></ng-transclude>
```

**myMap.component.ts**

```
this.transclude = {
    "mapClickHandler": "?mapClickHandler",
    "mapMarkerPopup": "?mapMarkerPopup"
}
```

Note that `map-click-handler` is placed directly inside a `<my-map>` component it transcludes correctly. So I know that a direct child transcludes correctly.

**mapMarkers.html**

```
<ui-gmap-markers></ui-gmap-markers>
<map-marker-popup></map-marker-popup>
```